# How to get user input in Docker with Go

Tags: docker, go

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    code, err := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.17

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app


CMD ["go","run","main.go"]
```

When create docker container and run it get and error like it:

[image]

I want to get user input from terminal when run docker container

Comment: How do you start your container? Do you provide the `-i` and `-t` flags to connect it to your terminal?

Comment: Thank you. In my case docker run with `-i` start working)

Answer (score 1):

By using `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` your user could pass parameters after the `docker run` command:

`ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "Hello World"]`

```
docker run <container-name>
> Hello World
```

```
docker run <container-name> test
> Hello World test
```

However you should use `os.Args` to retrieve those argument.

Comment: how does that answer the question ?

Comment: this is a way around since the question is unclear

Comment: the question is crystal clear. OP tries to open stdin but it was forecibly closed by docker because it was not running in interactive mode. What you suggest is not wrong, its not close to a workaround or a solution.